# Can I use the Arduino Uno's 3.3v pin while powered by a 9 volt battery?

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage-level

I have an Arduino Uno. It has a 3.3v pin that I would like to use to power another module that requires 3.3v, and nothing more. If I power my Arduino Uno with a 9 volt battery, will this pin output 3.3v, or will it give more than that?

Comment: It will output 3.3V. What module do you want to power ? A sensor uses very little current, that won't be a problem.

Comment: I am using an IMU sensor and an NRF radio. They both run on 3.3v.

Comment: A (fake) nRF24L01+ ? I think they require not a large amount of current (only 10mA or 20mA or so), but I'm not sure. I will probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.3v is regulated and will always output 3.3v if the device is powered on.